# Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem' when taking backup

Tags: magento-1, backup

We kept the scheduled backup in night.

but when we checked this , we are getting an error under `System > Tools > Backup`

> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Backup/Model/Fs/Collection.php on line 35

We have checked in var folder, there also no backup folder.

Comment: please check Filesystem.php exit at  your `magentoDir/lib/Varien/Data/Collection`

Comment: Filesystem.php is renamed as  Filesystem.php.suspected , how it happened ?

Comment: Just copy that  Filesystem.php   file from default magento .. put them that directory

Comment: any idea why it is suspected....

Comment: Your instace may be various effected... hosting provider may create this backup.

Comment: are you telling its affected by virus..?....

Comment: may be not sure 100%

Comment: you are Mr.perfectionist & you are making our community peRFect @7ochem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Filesystem.php` is `a library class file` which  basically exit at  your ***magentoDir/lib/Varien/Data/Collection***.

May be some reason it does not exist at  ***your magentoDir/lib/Varien/Data/Collection***

So my suggestion is to ***copy this file from a default magento instance*** and put that at  your error system.